# Hover Icons in Justified Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating  images grid  and I am using the following library [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/). The hover effect is working fine for the `img-alt` attribute. but I want to display some icons with links on the hover. 
Just like the following picture

[image]

Take a look the the following Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zvj2o7fy/1/embedded/result/

```
<div id="justifiedGallery">
  <a href="#" title="What's your destination?">
    <img alt="What's your destination?" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Just in a dream Place">
    <img alt="Just in a dream Place" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Il Capo at Palermo">
    <img alt="Il Capo at Palermo" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/226/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Erice">
    <img alt="Erice" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/240/227/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/127/300/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/440/227/?1" />

  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/227/?1" />

  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/240/227/?1" />
  </a>

  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
  </a>

  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
  </a>

  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/227/340/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/227/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
  </a>
  <a href="#" title="Truthful Innocence">
    <img alt="Truthful Innocence" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Please help me to create this.

Comment: which kind of icons you are using i mean image like.ico or glyphicons

Comment: @Tanmay I am using the https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ font toolkit

Comment: you are using some mobile js file ?which error you are getting as i am running it on fiddle it is giving me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined the same error you are getting?

Comment: No I am using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js ...But not able to add this JS on fiddle. Try this one @Tanmay

Comment: Can you just do a try Click the shield icon Mixed Content Shield in the address bar and choose Disable Protection

Comment: hi but i am doing in main site in http://codecanyon.net/item/justified-image-grid-premium-wordpress-gallery/full_screen_preview/2594251  in inspect element it is taking the icon i added there the link for bootstrap glyphicons and in span i put the class for a particular image hope i can share the image

Comment: try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvj2o7fy/8/) may it helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as per documentation(http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/captions/)
remove title attribute and add a div with class caption
just like

```
<a href="#">
    <img alt="What's your destination?" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
    <div class="caption">
        <div class="icon-cart">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-artistic-shopping-icons/32/shopping-32.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </a>
```

in this div you can add any thing.

If you need links on caption, need a small structure change like

```
<div id="justifiedGallery">
    <div>
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1">
            <img alt="Title 1" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1">
            <img alt="Title 1" src="http://lorempixel.com/340/227/?1" />
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use any `<a></a>` link inside the `<div class="caption">` Justified Gallery is shattered.

Answer (score 2):

Justified Gallery recommends using the [Colorbox jQuery library](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) inside of a callback to achieve what you are trying to do. Colorbox controls a `caption` lightbox div that gets shown on hover.

If you look at the [Colorbox 'multiple galleries with one call' demo](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/lightboxes/), you'll see you can add custom icons for each image by adding a hidden div called `caption` inside of the gallery container:

```
  <div class="container">
    <a href="image.jpg" class="jg-entry cboxElement">
      <img alt="Alt Message" src="image.jpg">
      <div class="caption">
       <div class="icon1"></div>
       <div class="icon2"></div>
       <div class="icon3"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

To invoke the captions and make them appear via JS, you'll make your call to Colobox inside of justified gallery's callback via the `.jg-complete` class. Inside of the callback, the colorbox library is invoked [with the necessary parameters](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) (like `opacity` and `transition` shown in the code sample below) to get your icons fading into view exactly you would like.

JS:

```
$('.container').justifiedGallery({
    rowHeight : 50 
}).on('jg.complete', function () {
    $(this).find('a').colorbox({
        maxWidth : '80%',
        maxHeight : '80%',
        opacity : 0.8,
        transition : 'elastic',
        current : ''
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically replace the caption with whatever you like. [Here's a quick solution](https://jsfiddle.net/zvj2o7fy/6/).

```
$("img").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".caption").html("<div><a href='#'><img src='source'></a>");
});
```

Comment: Looks fine @miraco But the problem is every icon has its own links. How can I put this as dynamic data.I am using this gallery on Asp.net `Datalist`

Comment: You could store the link(or just the part that is different between each image's link) in a "data-" attribute on the image and copy it from there to your caption.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery hover selector to set the display of icons 
The default display of icons should be none in css

This should help

https://codeshare.io/IGavT

Comment: While this might help out OP, please try to further explain how this can be achieved with a code example.